# Rewrite rule from directory to subdirectory in same domain

Tags: regex, apache, url, mod-rewrite

I have the following URL:

```
http://example.com/media/image.png
```

This should be redirected to:

```
http://example.com/media/images/image.png
```

This rule is only to redirect images in media folder.

But the rule should **NOT** redirect this kind of URLs:

```
http://example.com/some_folder/media/image.png
```

To:

```
http://example.com/media/images/image.png
```

How it should be?

I tried things like this:

```
RewriteRule /media/(.*) /media/images/$1 [R,L]
```

But I didn't get good results.

Comment: What does *I didn't get good results.* mean?

Comment: With that the first example didn't work. The second worked when it should not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to anchor your expression, otherwise it will match any URL *containing* `/media/` as opposed to *starting* with `media/`

```
RewriteRule ^media/(.*) /media/images/$1 [R,L]
```

If it's only images, you might want to consider making the expression more strict, such as:

```
RewriteRule ^media/(.+\.(jpe?g|gif|png)) /media/images/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: I realized that if the first URL exists, it redirects well. But if not, it takes me to a 404 page.
For example:
[http://example.com/media/image.png](http://example.com/media/image.png) 
If that url is 404, then nothing happen. If it exists then it takes me to [http://example.com/media/images/image.png](http://example.com/media/images/image.png) 

I think I have another problem to solve, but this rewrite should work. Thanks!